# Clojure Enlive: How to convert enlive nested map data back into HTML?

Tags: html, clojure, screen-scraping, enlive

I am writing a scraper for a site, and the goal is to create a reformatted version of the site. As part of the scraping, I dive into some comments, which might contain html formatting, so that we have:

> {... :content ("And, in a lower voice, \"Is this " {:tag :em, :attrs
>   nil, :content ("common")} "?\"")}

The question is: can I take the contents of this :content value and convert them into HTML using a built-in enlive function, like so:

> Is this <em>common</em>?

I can see how I might write something to handle these tags but I am extremely hesitant to homebrew anything because I am likely to miss edge cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not built in as far as I know and seems way too awfully specific for it to be built in. My solution:

```
(require '[net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html])

(def my-node '{:tag :p, 
               :content ("And, in a lower voice, \"Is this" 
                        {:tag :em, :attrs nil, :content ("common")} "?\"")})

;; for escaped string:
(apply str (html/emit* (:content my-node)))
=> "And, in a lower voice, \"Is this<em>common</em>?\""

;; print in human readable form
(print (apply str (html/emit* (:content my-node))))
=> And, in a lower voice, "Is this<em>common</em>?"
   nil
```